# python array index is not defined

Tags: python, arrays

I had trouble understanding the following code:

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    mylist = []
    maxlist = []
    for y in s:
        #here s is copied to mylist
        mylist.append(y)
        if y[i] == y[i+1]:
            if mylist > maxlist:
                maxlist = mylist
                mylist = ''
            continue
    return maxlist
```

print(lengthOfLongestSubstring('abcaabc'))

I get an error **"name 'i' is not defined"**--I do not understand this as i is just an index for **string y.** Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Its all right asking it here, but this is very basics of programming and is not exclusive to python. You can google it out "name not defined python error" and I guess you'll get your answer. Plus its really hard to analyse without the full code.

Answer (score 0):

A program just follow your instruction and your instruction has to be clear.

You did not define what is i in your code. Python doesn't know what is i, does it take value 0? does it take value 1? should it stop before visiting every character of y?

I suspect that you might want to include another loop inside the current for loop (with y as the iteration variable) to go through the string y.

Also, another potential problem:

- I notice that you are comparing two list. mylist and maxlist. You have to think about what does it mean by a list is bigger than another list? If you want the list with more elements, you can compare len(mylist) with len(maxlist).